# Fix bad encode symfony to cmd

Tags: cmd, character-encoding, symfony

when I try to introduce something the console with bin / console, for example:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

The output of cmd returns these characters

[image]

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

What you see are [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). Linux and OS X systems should support them natively.

But on Windows, you'll either need to use an emulated terminal like Cygwin or a Windows implementation of an ANSI capable terminal, like ANSICON to see the output as it was meant to be. Also see the note in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/coloring.html) about this for further alternatives/possibilities.